# CSS styles not working spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i am creating the spring boot project header section but my css styles are not working what tried so far i attached below.

Error displayed **GET http://localhost:8010/static/css/topbar.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404**

i created css folder **resources/static/css**

**css**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
.navbar {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Added the following code to header.html at src/main/resources/templates.

```
<head th:fragment="header">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  th:href="@{/static/css/topbar.css}"/>

</head>
```

but not working the styles

Answer (score 0):

Try `th:href="@{/css/topbar.css}"` without `/static`.
Spring Boot will server what's inside "static" folder, but not the "static" folder itself.